# java проверка целое число

Tags: java

Ув. коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести на печать также сообщение, что число является составным. Спасибо!

```
int n=9;    

for (int i=2; i<n; i++)
{

    if ((n%i)==0) 
    { 

        System.out.println (n+"-is not prime number ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Очевидно, `System.out.println("Число является целым");`. Не благодарите.

Comment: первый раз здесь, извините. Не весь текст почему-то в вопросе. Имеется в виду, чтобы в двух строках выводить ответ - если целое или нет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

решил так

```
public class cycles3   {

    public static void main (String []args)    {    
        int n=9; 
        int m=0;
        for (int i=2; i<n; i++) {
            if (n%i==0) 
            {
                m++;
            } 
        }
        if (m==0) 
        {
            System.out.println (n+"-is the prime number ");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println (n+"-is not prime number ");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double toTest = 23.23d;

int flooredValue = (int) toTest;

double resultDouble = (double)toTest - flooredValue;

if(resultDouble == 0)
{
    System.out.println("целое");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("НЕ целое");
}
```

---

Для проверки же на простоту числа ваш код можно использовать так:

Создать boolean переменную со значением `true`, коей назначить false, если условие выполнится. После цикла проверить итоговое значение.

Comment: Спасибо, а в рамках кода в вопросе это возможно?

Comment: @avs6337, мне совершенно не понятно как приведённый вами код должен решать поставленную вами задачу. Засим я не могу вам ответить как можно его модифицировать. У вас же там узнаётся делится ли без остатка заданное число на все числа от 2 до n.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне кажется автор перепутал целый и простой)

Comment: мысль была в том, что если заданное число делится без остатка хотя бы на одно число, значит - оно не простое.

Comment: да - извините - перепутал целое с простым

Comment: @avs6337, дополнил ответ

Comment: @avs6337, если один из представленный ответов решил вашу задачу, то вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав галочку слева от тела ответа. Если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, то вы можете опубликовать свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
    class TrueFals{
      public static boolean isDivisible(double n, double m){
        double x = n / m;
        return ((x % 1) == 0);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n = in.nextInt();
        double m = in.nextInt();
        boolean tf = isDivisible(n, m);
        System.out.println(tf);
      }
    }
```